# Get total size of jpeg images per directory in each directory containing jpegs

Tags: bash, shell, find

I'm trying to get a per-directory total size of all the `.jpg`/`.jpeg` images in each directory that contains such images. And showing the full directory path.

I've managed to cobble this together from various bits I've found.

```
for i in $(tree -dfi --noreport); do
  find . \( -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.jpeg" \) -type f -exec du -c {} \; $i
done
```

However I'm getting an error:

```
find: paths must precede expression
```

Anyone know what I've done wrong?
Or can suggest any alternatives with bash that might do what I'm looking for?

I get the same error when changing it to this:

```
for i in $(tree -dfi --noreport); do
  find $i \( -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.jpeg" \) -type f -exec du {} \; $i
done
```

Comment: Is `$i` the directory where you want to search for jp[e]g images, that is, the path? If so, "[the] path[s] must precede the expression" (the bit where you put the `-iname`s). Why do you have a `.` after `find` instead of `$i`?

Comment: Question edited. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Remove the `$i` at the end...

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in $(tree -dfi --noreport); do
    find $i -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.jpeg" \) -exec du {} \;
done
```

Drop the path name at the end of the `find` command and `-type` option should appear before any other options to make search a bit faster. This should do it.

By the way, to help you a bit, I would have done this in this way:

```
for i in $( tree -dfi --noreport ); do 
    find $i -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -or -iname "*.jpeg" \) -exec du '{}' \; | awk -v d=$i '{ j+=$1; } END{ printf("%s: %d\n", d, j) }' | grep -Ev ": 0$"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Though it doesn't do what I was hoping. Also I think it borks on dir names containing spaces. A fault in my original approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate error is that extra `$i` at the end of the `find` invocation — just remove it. The order of arguments for `find` is first the directories to traverse, then the expression to match.

I don't get the point of the call to `tree`: `find` can do this. With GNU find (i.e. on Linux or Cygwin), assuming your directories don't contain insanely many `.jpg` files, the `-execdir` primary on `find` lets you run a command on all the matching files in a directory.

```
find . \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' \) -execdir sh -c 'echo "$(du -c "$@" | sed -n "\$s/\\t.*//p") ${PWD#$0/}"' $PWD {} +
```

Note that versions of GNU find prior to 4.5.9 have a [bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?19593) that causes `-execdir … {} +` to run one command per file, which is no good here. So you may have to work harder.

You can traverse the directory tree in bash. Set the `globstar` option to enable the pattern `**/`, which matches any number of subdirectory levels, i.e. it enumerates subdirectories recursively. In each subdirectory, if there are JPEG files, call `du` to compute their total size.

```
shopt -s globstar
for d in **/*/; do
  files=("$d/"*.jpg "$d/"*.jpeg)
  total=$(du -s -- "$files" 2>/dev/null | tail -n 1)
  total=${total%$'\t'*}
  echo "$total"$'\t'"$d"
done
```

Comment: Nice one... that one liner works beautifully. Nice tip on `-execdir` as well. Also seems to work with dir names containing spaces. I'm only just getting started with bash but I love how there are so many ways to do things like this. I couldn't find a way to do this under Windows so mounted the SMB share and ran this command. Nice!

Comment: Also I did need `-iname` though as it was missing some directories containing .JPG/.JPEG files

Comment: Actually I just noticed one thing, the same directory often appears twice with different sizes reported

Comment: @benbradley The `-execdir` one-liner unfortunately only works on very recent (and IIRC a few older versions) of GNU find. I think most currently deployed systems have a buggy version where this reports every file independently. Try the bash loop (beware that I haven't tested it).